# WCF Server side logging message send back progress

Tags: wcf

I am getting timeouts on the client side and I am not sure if the issue is the package size or the network.

On the server side is there a way of logging the progress of the message being sent to the client?
Or at least the size of the package being sent on the transport layer?

Note: I've looked into WCF Logging options before posting question, but couldn't find anything regarding the message size, especially if binding is not Http so there is no specific header with the Content-Length.

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've already looked into microsoft docs but couldn't find anything about the payload logging. Which part of the doc are you referring to?

Comment: You can enable trace on `System.ServiceModel.Serialization` to log the messages being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your config file these lines:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" initializeData="c:\MyTracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

More information you can find on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342(v=vs.110).aspx) page.

Comment: So which setting is for the message size? I don't want to log entire message to the log.

Comment: @user007 - if you open msdn page, which I attached, then you will find proper documentation fragment. Regards

Comment: I've already looked through the msdn docs before posting this question, I've opened your link again but I am still not sure what are you referring to.
In you config settings you have set to logEntireMessage and that would be in 100s of Mb for me. I still wont get the message size.

Answer (score 0):

This was the best thing I did manage to achieve, couldn't find anything out of the box:

```
public class MessageSizeBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageSizeInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }
}

public class MessageSizeInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return request;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reply.IsFault || reply.IsEmpty) return;

            var buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
            var messageBodyReader = buffer.CreateMessage().GetReaderAtBodyContents();
            var messageBody = messageBodyReader.ReadOuterXml();

            LogMessageSize(messageBody);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    private void LogMessageSize(string messageBody)
    {
        double messageSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(messageBody);
        Debug.WriteLine("Message size in MBytes {0}", messageSize / 1024 / 1024);
    }
}
```